# How to validate objects from reverse side of foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have two objects that are connected together by a ForeignKey.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.Charfield()

class AnswerOption(models.Model):
    text = models.Charfield()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="options")
```

When `Question` is created in the admin interface I'm using a Inline form for `AnswerOptions` so that they can be created at the same time. I'd like to perform some validation on the `Question` and it needs access to the new `AnswerOptions` to make the decision.

I've added a `clean` method to `Question` but the `options` property is empty.

What is the correct way to validate `Question`?

[EDIT]
Made it clear that `Question` needs access to the `AnswerOptions` to be able to validate everything.

[EDIT]
Added explicit reference to using an InlineForm for `AnswerOptions` in the admin interface.

Comment: Can you validate each of the AnswerOptions individually? Or do they need to know about each other. The reason you're running into problems here is because you need to create the question before creating the answer options. That causes `Question.clean` to run before any `AnswerOption`'s `clean`'s are run.

Comment: Can you specify which validations ?, post the clean method also.

Comment: @schillingt The AnswerOptions need to know about each other and the Question. For instance I want to make sure AnswerOptions aren't repeated.

Comment: @jsanchezs The contents of the clean method don't really matter, the Question needs to know about the different AnswerOptions to make a decision.

Comment: @Ben: Did you get your issue worked out? I see that you're using an inline form...

Comment: @BrianDant I just posted a solution that worked for me. Feedback welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've discovered:

When creating Inline forms in the admin interface Django creates a `Formset` to handle the multiple forms. (The example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) is the same as my use case)

`Formsets` have a `clean()` method like other forms and they have a `forms` property to access the child forms.
Just like normal forms they have an `instance` property that refers to the 'base' class and the individual forms have an `instance` property that gets you a instance of the newly submitted data.

Putting it all together:

```
# models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.Charfield()

class AnswerOption(models.Model):
    text = models.Charfield()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="options")

# admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

class AnswerOptionFormset(BaseInlineFormset):
    def clean(self):
        super().clean() # See note in docs about calling this to check unique constraints

        #self.instance -> Question, with all the newly submitted, and validated, data.
        #self.forms -> iterator over all the submitted AnswerOption forms
        #for f in self.forms:
        #    f.instance -> instance of AnswerOption containing the new validated data

        #Note: self.instance.options will refer to the previous AnswerOptions

        #raise ValidationError for anything that is wrong.
        #It is also possible to modify the data in self.instance or form.instance instead.


class AnswerOptionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    formset = AnswerOptionFormset # note formset on AnswerOption NOT QuestionAdmin 


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerOptionInline]
```

Comment: Your original reply put me on the right path. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this through a Django form, which have a more robust interface for
validation. The `clean` method on your form is the place for this type
of validation.

```py
# forms.py 

from django import forms
from .models import Question

class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    text = models.Charfield()

    class Meta:
        model = Question

    def clean(self):
        options = self.cleaned_data['options']
        if not option.are_ok:
          raise forms.ValidationError
```

```py
# admin.py

from django import admin
from .forms import QuestionForm


class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = QuestionForm

...
```

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/):

> The form subclass’s clean() method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address”. This method can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the cleaned_data.

Comment: I've realized the problem is that I'm using an InlineForm in the admin interface to create a ```Question``` and ```AnswerOption```s at the same time. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: When you are in the clean method of the question, can you tell me the value of AnswerOption.objects.all()? And also AnswerOption.objects.filter(question=self)?